# What is p.p.t simulator?

Tags: encryption, garbled-circuits

I was reading research paper [Reusable Garbled circuit](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/733.pdf) in which i read the term "**p.p.t Simulator**" and p.p.t Algorithm. I know about Probablistic Polynomial Time(p.p.t) Algorithm. Kindly someone tell me what is Probablistic Polynomial Time Simulator

Comment: Since we expect **a significant amount of research** before you ask here, please add some information which explains... What research have you done? What were your findings? What stopped you from finding the answer yourself? After all, a quick search for ***"probabilistic polynomial time simulator"*** using a random search engine returns ample results, including papers and websites explaining what they are and when the are used. Currently, its unclear to me what stopped you from learning about them yourself. Or is there something specific you don't understand in relation to such simulators?

Answer (score 2):

A PPT *simulator* is really just a PPT algorithm. So if you know what a PPT algorithm is then you know what a PPT simulator is as well.

The term simulator is used in many contexts in cryptography, but typically they are PPT algorithms that are supposed to produce output according to some distribution *simulating* the output distributions of one or more parties in some protocol.